# Error when running vim with dein

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I tried to install dein and run vim, but this error has occured.

```
Error detected while processing function dein#begin[1]..dein#util#_begin[6]..dein#util#_error[1]..<SNR>5_msg2list:
line    1:
E121: Undefined variable: v:t_list
E15: Invalid expression: type(a:expr) ==# v:t_list ? a:expr : split(a:expr, '\n')
Error detected while processing function dein#begin[1]..dein#util#_begin[6]..dein#util#_error:
line    1:
E714: List required
```

I clone dein and put this repository `~/.cache/dein/repos/github.com/Shougo/dein.vim`, and rest of the settings are followed by the document.

Why this error happened and how to solve it?

Thanks,

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: dein.vim [requires](https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim#requirements) vim 8. What version of `vim` do you have? Show us `vim --version`.